# How to check SQLite connection's threading mode?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to check the [threading mode](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) of an active SQLite connection? I know about [`sqlite3_threadsafe()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/threadsafe.html), but

> The return value of the sqlite3_threadsafe() function shows only the compile-time setting of thread safety, not any run-time changes to that setting made by sqlite3_config().

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, seven year old question. You have answered it yourself, though. For the next person who comes looking:

sqlite3_db_mutex will return NULL if threading mode is Single-thread or Multi-thread.

So we have:

(sqlite3_threadsafe , sqlite3_db_mutex) : threading mode

(0 , NULL) : Single-thread

(1 , NULL) : Mutli-thread

(1 , valid) : Serialized

Comment: No, `sqlite3_threadsafe` doesn't tell you if the _current_ threading mode is single-thread or multi-thread, that's the problem.

Comment: no such function: sqlite3_threadsafe and no such function: sqlite3_mutex. i am getting this error

Comment: I've found only struct `sqlite3_mutex` , not function, in documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Updated the answer to use the proper function name `sqlite3_db_mutex`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer:

> ```
> sqlite3_mutex *sqlite3_db_mutex(sqlite3*);
> ```
>
> This interface returns a pointer the
>   sqlite3_mutex object that serializes
>   access to the database connection
>   given in the argument when the
>   threading mode is Serialized. If the
>   threading mode is Single-thread or
>   Multi-thread then this routine returns
>   a NULL pointer.

Now I only need a way to distinguish Single-thread from Multi-thread...

Comment: Could you please give detailed steps to check threading mode at runtime. I am getting following error. no such function: sqlite3_threadsafe and no such function: sqlite3_mutex